# How to check the uploaded file for image

Tags: php, image, filter, detect

I know methods with `getimagesize` and `Fileinfo` extension in PHP, but all of them requires some libraries(`GD` or `Fileinfo`).

I find this code for detect image from provided file:

```
function is_image($image_path)
{
    if (!$f = fopen($image_path, 'rb'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $data = fread($f, 8);
    fclose($f);

    // signature checking
    $unpacked = unpack("H12", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == '474946383961' || array_pop($unpacked) == '474946383761') return "gif";
    $unpacked = unpack("H4", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == 'ffd8') return "jpg";
    $unpacked = unpack("H16", $data);
    if (array_pop($unpacked) == '89504e470d0a1a0a') return "png";

    return false;
}
```

Is it a secure? Whether or not to use it?

Comment: using getimagesize() is the best option. Your code is just checking the header of the image, what if some malicious injected in the middle of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote from the PHP documentation for the `getimagesize` function:-

> This function does not require the GD image library.

So you should be ok to use it.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. Not noticed that.